# Table storage RowKey ,Partition Key

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-function-app-proxy

Could someone please tell me whether it is possible to assign same value for both Partitionkey and Rowkey in Azure Functionapp?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but partition key and row key are separate properties. Did you run into an issue?

Comment: yes.when I assign same value for rowkey and partition key in the eventhub trigger javascript functionapp ..there is an exception .The inpt for functionapp is iothub and output is azure table storage.                           
 {var date = Date.now();
var partitionKey = date+ ' ';
 var rowKey = date + '';
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I just created my Http Trigger for Node.js to check this issue.

**function.json:**

```html
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outputTable",
      "tableName": "emails",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**index.js:**

```
var date=Date.now();
var key=date+'-'+Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);
context.bindings.outputTable = {
    "partitionKey": key,
    "rowKey":key,
    "GPIOPin":2,
    'status':true
};
```

Leverage [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) to check my table as follows:

[image]

For more details about the output sample for Table storage binding, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#storage-table-output-binding).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. The design consequences will be that you will have partitions with a size of one entity. Remember that batch operations and transaction support are limited to entities in the same partition.